# XML STORING PROJECT. How is best?

Tags: java, xml, frameworks

My application contains a set of model  e.g. DocumentX2010, DocumentX2009, DocumentX2008...

Every year document changes persistance model.

More fields..

More details...

Some little difference...
Every year I need to change the database column...

For next version of my project I want to change the architecture drastically. 
I want to store  documents in XML format.

I search standard to design mi xml files:
some like CDA2 (The HL7 Clinical Document Architecture is an XML-based markup standard intended to specify the encoding, structure and semantics of clinical documents for exchange.)

How is best standard?

How is it best framework to mapping my java classes to the XML file?

How is it best way to persist XML file into DB?

Comment: Do you need to query the documents that you store - how do you intend to retrieve them?

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a standard for your document design is like looking for a standard for your database data model: The design is entirely dependent on your domain and application, there is no external answer (unless you are using a shared established standard, which do publish xsd's, and I reckon this is not your case).

I'd say the best way to serialize a Java class to xml would be to convert it into a bean and use [xmlencoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html).

For persisting, you may check xml databases if you are feeling adventurous. Otherwise, you can convert your beans into entity beans and use JPA.

Comment: See this for example: http://hl7book.net/index.php?title=CDA  
It's a good standard for Clinical Document. But I need some standard for economic Document. About serialization... Serialize whit xmlencoder is not a good solution, there are a lot of better framework... with validation  whit marshalling... I search to develop more sophisticated solution.

Comment: That is a shared established standard that does publish an xsd. XML/EDIFACT would be another. But those are specifications that you conform to if you are required to communicate to third parties implementing the said specification. They are not guidelines for you about how to represent your data.

Comment: I don't really understand why you are differentiating marshalling, in this context it's synonymous with serialization; and I'd reckon you'd implement your validation on the object yourself (in any framework you'd define your own validation criteria). You can use Spring O/X if you are going to use the customization capabilities offered, there is nothing that would motivate its use when the need is only serialization and validation.

Comment: Yes It'true in this context it's synonymous... I need a Java binding framework able to unmarshal XML data, validate and modify Java content objects, and marshal Java content back to XML data. Whit only xmlencoder it' hardwork for me... I try to read about Spring O/X... thanks

Comment: JAXB looks good. With a simple maven plugin generates POJO classes from xml schema. Moreover, he adds validation and the various functions. Sounds like a good idea?
But does anyone know a good software for designing XML schemas?